# Neural network detecting camera position change between two images

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to train a model on a set of photos with camera position and camera angle as the output, but I can't find information about network architecture accepting two pictures as the input. What should I focus about?

Comment: It's just data. Concatenate the two images, i.e., first  half of array is first image, second half is second image, and train on the expected output and let the magic of neural networks figure out the correlation in the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keras provide two types of model api

1. Sequential: Which is used for linear model 1 input 1 output all in sequence
2. Model api: which is used to make model of any input tensor and any output tensors.

for your problem model can form like this:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, concatenate, add, Dense, Conv2d
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

input1 = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))  # where (224, 224, 3) is the image dimensions
input2 = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))  #I'm supposing your both images have same shape
x = concatenate([input1, input2]) or add([input1, input2]) #whatever suits
x = Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding='same')(x) #taking input above layer for this(Conv2D) layer
x = Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding='same')(x) #taking input above layer for this(Conv2D) layer
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(10)(x)
model = Model([ipnut1, input2], x)   #this keras Model Functional api took two arguments 1. list of input tensor or a input tensor   2. list of output tensor or a tensor
model.summary()

Model: "functional_1"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 224, 224, 3) 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_2 (InputLayer)            [(None, 224, 224, 3) 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate (Concatenate)       (None, 224, 224, 6)  0           input_1[0][0]                    
                                                                 input_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d (Conv2D)                 (None, 224, 224, 32) 1760        concatenate[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)               (None, 224, 224, 32) 9248        conv2d[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)               (None, 1605632)      0           conv2d_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)                 (None, 10)           16056330    flatten[0][0]                    
==================================================================================================
Total params: 16,067,338
Trainable params: 16,067,338
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Here is your model with two inputs as image

[image: here is the visualisation of the model]